# Taylor expansion of $e^z$ - some doubts on an approximation regarding terms from the third-order one onward

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion, infinitesimals

I quote *Jacod-Protter* herebelow.

> Let $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of Poisson random variables with parameter $\lambda_n=n$.

($\ldots$)

> We have 
>   \begin{equation*}
> \begin{split}
> E\big\{e^{iuZ_n}\big\}&=E\Bigg\{e^{iu\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(X_n-n\right)\right)}\Bigg\}\\ &=e^{-iu\sqrt{n}}E\Big\{e^{i\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}X_n}\Big\}\\&=e^{-iu\sqrt{n}}e^{n\left(e^{iu/\sqrt{n}-1}-1\right)}
> \end{split}
> \end{equation*}
>   where the last equality follows from the fact that if $X\sim\text{Poisson}\left(\lambda\right)$, $\varphi_X(u)=E\{iuX\}=e^{\lambda\left(e^{iu}-1 \right)}$.
>  Continuing and using a Taylor expansion for $e^z$, we have the above equals
>   \begin{equation*}
> \begin{split}
> &=e^{-iu\sqrt{n}}e^{n\left(i\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{u^2}{2n}-\frac{iu^3}{6n^{3/2}}+ \hspace{0.2cm}\cdots\right)}\\&=e^{-iu\sqrt{n}+iu\sqrt{n}}e^{-u^2/2}e^{-\frac{h(u, n)}{\sqrt{n}}}\\&=e^{-u^2/2}e^{-\frac{h(u, n)}{\sqrt{n}}}
> \end{split}
> \end{equation*}
>   **where $h(u,n)$ stays bounded in $n$ for each $u$ and hence $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{h(u,n)}{\sqrt{n}}=0$**

I got three doubts referring to part in bold above:
 1. *Why is one allowed to **precisely** say that $-\frac{iu^3}{6n^{3/2}}+ \hspace{0.2cm}\cdots=\frac{h(u,n)}{\sqrt{n}}$?*;
 2. *What does it mean that "$h(u,n)$ stays bounded in $n$ for each $u$"? And how can I show this?*; 
 3. *$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{h(u,n)}{\sqrt{n}}=0$ since $\sqrt{n}$ goes to $+\infty$ faster than $h(u,n)$, right? If so, I would argue that $h(u,n)$ is of an infinitesimal order which is lower than that of $\sqrt{n}$, but I cannot see why it is so* (as it is clear from point $2.$ right above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, let $X_n \sim Poiss(n)$ and let $Z_n = \sqrt{n}(Z_n- n)$. We want to calculate $\varphi_n(u) = \mathbb E[\exp(iuZ_n)]$. We get:

$\varphi_n(u) = \exp(-iu\sqrt{n})\mathbb E[\exp(iu \frac{X_n}{\sqrt{n}})] = \exp(-iu\sqrt{n})e^{n(\exp(iu\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})-1)}$.

Now, $\exp(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}$, so that we can write:
 $\exp( iu\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k! (\sqrt{n})^k}i^ku^k = 1 + iu\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} -\frac{u^2}{2n}+ \sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{1}{k! (\sqrt{n})^k}i^ku^k$, which gives:

$$\varphi_n(u) = \exp(-\frac{u^2}{2})\exp(\sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{1}{k! (\sqrt{n})^k}i^ku^k)$$

Now, what's done in your case, was just saying that $\sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{1}{k! (\sqrt{n})^k}i^ku^k = \frac{h(n,u)}{\sqrt{n}} $

$\bf {Question \ 1}$: They just defined function $h$ in that way, there is nothing more.

$\bf {Question \ 2}$: It means that for fixed $u \in \mathbb R$, sequence $(h(n,u))_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is bounded, that is $\forall _{u \in \mathbb R} \exists_{M_u \in \mathbb R_+}$ such that $\forall_{n \in \mathbb N}: |h(n,u)| \le M_u$.

And why is that? Note that $|h(n,u)| = |\sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{1}{k! (\sqrt{n})^{k-1}}i^ku^k | \le \sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{|u|^k}{k! \sqrt{n}^{k-1}} \le \sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{|u|^k}{k!} \le \exp(|u|)$, so for fixed $u$, sequence $h(n,u)$ is bounded.

$\bf {Question \ 3}$: Using 2), we get for any fixed $u \in \mathbb R$, that $0 \le \frac{|h(n,u)|}{\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{\exp(|u|)}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$, so for any fixed $u \in \mathbb R$, we get that $\frac{h(n,u)}{\sqrt{n}}$ tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, so for any fixed $u \in \mathbb R$, we get $\varphi_n(u) \to \exp(-\frac{u^2}{2})$ and now apply Levy continuous Theorem.

Comment: Thank you a lot for all your effort, time and help. So grateful :) @DominikKutek